# Zend Framework: Redirector behaves differently between Dev and Test environments

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am writing a Zend Framework application and am testing with PHPUnit.  My problem is that there is one small section of code where the Redirector action helper is behaving differently between my Development and Testing environments.

Here's the code:

```
if($user == NULL) {
    $this->_logger->info('EMAIL NOT FOUND!');
    $this->_flash->addMessage('User not found');
    $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'index');
    $this->_logger->info('SHOULD NEVER GET TO THIS LINE!');                    
}
```

When I run it in a browser in my Development environment, I get the following log entry:

```
2011-08-02T09:51:58+10:00 INFO (6): Controller: Myapplication_UserController
2011-08-02T09:51:58+10:00 INFO (6): EMAIL NOT FOUND!
2011-08-02T09:51:58+10:00 INFO (6): Controller: Myapplication_IndexController
2011-08-02T09:51:58+10:00 INFO (6): Service: Myapplication_Service_Authentication
```

Perfect.  When my PHPUnit tests run it, however, I get these log entries:

```
2011-08-02T09:52:39+10:00 INFO (6): Controller: Myapplication_UserController
2011-08-02T09:52:39+10:00 INFO (6): EMAIL NOT FOUND!
2011-08-02T09:52:39+10:00 INFO (6): SHOULD NEVER GET TO THIS LINE!
2011-08-02T09:52:39+10:00 INFO (6): Controller: Myapplication_ErrorController
2011-08-02T09:52:39+10:00 INFO (6): Service: Myapplication_Service_Authentication
```

Grrr!  Why is it executing lines below the redirection?

A couple of other points to note:

- I have exactly the same line, `$this->_helper->redirector('index', 'index')`, elsewhere in the same class and function, and it works fine in both Dev and Test environments;
- I have checked htaccess, index.php, application.ini and bootstrap.php, and can find no differences in the error reporting between the two environments
- My test classes extend Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase

Any ideas?  Much appreciated!

Comment: Could something be overwriting the redirector's default "redirect and exit" behaviour?

Comment: Phil, nothing as far as I can see.  Also, the code works fine elsewhere in the same function.

Comment: CLI vs. SAPI? How do you invoke PHPUnit? Are you sure the redirect works in CLI mode?

Comment: hakre, I can invoke PHPUnit via either netbeans, or via command line.  Either way, I get the same response.  redirect must be working via CLI, since the problem line of code is working elsewhere in the class/function fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirector helper has a boolean member call $_exit that will tell it whether or not to exit when redirect is called.

In your case, somewhere this member is being set to false and the redirect isn't exiting.

The Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase class that you're using sets the $_exit member of the redirector to false.

This is done so that when you unit test a redirect won't cause PHPUnit to just stop executing. If this wasn't done then your tests would stop running half-way through every time.

That is why you get the unwanted log message, because the redirector isn't exiting.

Please refer to the section titled 
'Controller Tests and the Redirector Action Helper' at this [link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.test.phpunit.html)